# How to use mousePressed() for 2 different events in processing?

Tags: processing

I am working on my university project and came across an issue. I am creating a visualization for some data and want to use `mousePressed()` for different events, but when I try to add another event to `mousePressed()` it will not run as the code does not know which event to run (when the mouse is pressed it fires both events).

I made an event that allows the user to click the main menu buttons and want to make another event when the user is in the `pieChartPage()`, they are able to click on the PS_Button (which is a PlayStation Logo) to display a description. Right now the user is able to hover over the PS_Button and the description appears but I want the user to click on the PS_Button so that the description stays on the screen. I created a class 'ImageButton' for the description formatting and I am not sure how, if possible, to add the `mousePressed()` code into that class and still work with the rest of the code.

Here is my code:

In the `setup()` `draw()` page: `mousePressed()` - line 180, `pieChartPage()` - line 244
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1d5y2Ksq-y05J8tLiyK-1P2uwLjBhm-iH?usp=sharing

The link contains the code and the data used within the code.
Any help would be very appreciated, thank you.

`setup()` `draw()`:

```
PieChart pieChart; //pie chart 
PImage PS_Button, XBOX_Button, NINTENDO_Button;  //creating variables for the images to be used 
ImageButton psImageDscpt, xboxImageDscpt, nintendoImageDscpt;


void setup() {
  size(1200, 800);
  //functions to make the render of the program Apple Retina displays and Windows High-DPI displays look smoother and less pixelated
  pixelDensity(2); 
  smooth();

  loadData();

  //Pie Chart
  //pie chart for pie chart page
  pieChart = new PieChart();
  psImageDscpt = new ImageButton("Sony", 800, 480, 300, 200);
  xboxImageDscpt = new ImageButton("Microsoft", 20, 425, 250, 200);
  nintendoImageDscpt = new ImageButton("Nintendo", 925, 75, 200, 300);
}

void draw() {
  switch(state) {
  case 2:
    // pie chart
    pieChartPage();
    drawMenuButton();
    break;
  case 3:
    bubbleChartPage();
    drawMenuButton();
    // pie chart
    break;
  case 4:
    scatterGraphPage();
    drawMenuButton();
    // pie chart
    break;
  default:
    // menu
    // the default case means "everything else" and in our case it will be the menu so you cannot have an impossible case
    drawMenu();
    drawMenuButton();
  }
}
```

Current `mousePressed()` and commented is the code I want to add:

```
void mousePressed() {
  switch(state) {
  case 2:     // pie chart page
    ClickedMenuButton();
    println("Going back to state home from PC");
    //state = 1;
    break;
  case 3:      // bubble chart page
    ClickedMenuButton();
    println("Going back to state home from BG");
    break;
  case 4:      // scatter graph page
    ClickedMenuButton();
    println("Going back to state home from SG");
    break;
  default:
    // menu
    ClickMenu();
  }
}

//void mousePressed() {
//  if ( mouseX > psImgX && mouseX < (psImgX + PS_Button.width) && mouseY > psImgY && mouseY < (psImgY + PS_Button.height)) {
//    psImageDscpt.drawPieChartDscpt();
//  }
//}
```

void `pieChartPage()` in `setup()` `draw()` page:

```
//page for pie chart visualisation
void pieChartPage() {
  background(10);
  //psImgX = 100;
  //psImgY = 50;
  //xboxImgX = 200;
  //xboxImgY = 50;
  //nintendoImgX = 300;
  //nintendoImgY = 50;

  PS_Button = loadImage("ps_logo.png");    //loading images from program folder
  psLegend = loadImage("ps_logo.png");
  XBOX_Button = loadImage("xbox_logo.png");
  xboxLegend = loadImage("xbox_logo.png");
  NINTENDO_Button = loadImage("nintendo_logo.png");
  nintendoLegend = loadImage("nintendo_logo.png");

  //int psImgX, psImgY, xboxImgX, xboxImgY, nintendoImgX, nintendoImgY;

  PS_Button.resize(100, 0);  //size of the button, all are the same 
  XBOX_Button.resize(100, 0);
  NINTENDO_Button.resize(100, 0);
  psLegend.resize(75, 0);
  xboxLegend.resize(75, 0);
  nintendoLegend.resize(125, 0);

  tint(225);// set tint of buttons to be zero
  image(PS_Button, psImgX, psImgY); //drawing image to the screen
  image(XBOX_Button, xboxImgX, xboxImgY);
  image(NINTENDO_Button, nintendoImgX, nintendoImgY);
  //drawing legend and tints represent the company's colour respectively
  tint(pieChartColours[1]);
  image(psLegend, 65, 75);
  tint(pieChartColours[2]);
  image(xboxLegend, 65, 175);
  tint(pieChartColours[0]);
  image(nintendoLegend, 45, 285);

  pieChart.pieChart(width/2, height/2, 400, values_PieChart, pieChartColours); //draws the pie chart into the window 

  textSize(12);
  if (mouseX > psImgX && mouseX < (psImgX + PS_Button.width) && mouseY > psImgY && mouseY < (psImgY + PS_Button.height)) {
    psImageDscpt.drawPieChartDscpt();
  } else if (mouseX > xboxImgX && mouseX < (xboxImgX + XBOX_Button.width) && mouseY > xboxImgY && mouseY < (xboxImgY + XBOX_Button.height)) {
    xboxImageDscpt.drawPieChartDscpt();
  } else if (mouseX > nintendoImgX && mouseX < (nintendoImgX + NINTENDO_Button.width) && mouseY > nintendoImgY && mouseY < (nintendoImgY + NINTENDO_Button.height)) {
    nintendoImageDscpt.drawPieChartDscpt();
  } else {
    psImageDscpt.drawPieChartDscpt();
    xboxImageDscpt.drawPieChartDscpt();
    nintendoImageDscpt.drawPieChartDscpt();
  }
  
  //legend text
  fill(225);
  text("Sony / PlayStation", 55, 150);
  text("Microsoft / XBOX", 52.5, 260);
  text("Nintendo", 80, 340);  
  textSize(40);
  fill(pieChartColours[0]);
  text("/50", 230, 330);
  fill(pieChartColours[1]);
  text("/50", 215, 130);
  fill(pieChartColours[2]);
  text("/50", 185, 230);
  
  fill(150,0,0);
  textSize(60);
  text("64%", 590, 350);
  fill(0,150,0);
  textSize(20);
  text("7%", 460, 465);
  fill(0,0,150);
  textSize(40);
  text("11%", 565, 525);
  
  
  homeButtonBar.Draw();
}
```

ImageButton class:

```
class ImageButton {
  String pieDscptLabel;
  int xPos1, yPos1, xPos2, yPos2;
  float wDiam1, hDiam1;

  ImageButton (String pieDscptLabel, int xPos1, int yPos1, float wDiam1, float hDiam1) {
    this.pieDscptLabel=pieDscptLabel;
    this.xPos1=xPos1;
    this.yPos1=yPos1;
    this.wDiam1=wDiam1;
    this.hDiam1=hDiam1;
  }

  void drawPieChartDscpt() { //draws the bubbles description
    noFill();
    stroke(225);
    rect(xPos1, yPos1, wDiam1, hDiam1, 20);
    textAlign(LEFT, BASELINE);
    fill(200);
    text(pieDscptLabel, xPos1+10, yPos1+20);
  }

  void mousePressed() {
    if ( mouseX > psImgX && mouseX < (psImgX + PS_Button.width) && mouseY > psImgY && mouseY < (psImgY + PS_Button.height)) {
      psImageDscpt.drawPieChartDscpt();
      println("it works");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you don't need to write two `mousePressed()` method, just test the cases inside the method to  differentiate which case you are working on, after some reading I figured your `state` variable equals 2 when the user is on `pieChartPage()` So I moved your code inside the first `mousePressed()` and added the test, the method call to draw description works fine but you will have to change it to switch between visible/invisible instead of drawing when the user click, here is the updated code:

```
void mousePressed() {
  if(state == 2)
  {
    if ( mouseX > psImgX && mouseX < (psImgX + PS_Button.width) && mouseY > psImgY && mouseY < (psImgY + PS_Button.height)) 
    {
      psImageDscpt.drawPieChartDscpt();
    }
  }
  
  switch(state) {
  case 2:     // pie chart page
    ClickedMenuButton();
    println("Going back to state home from PC");
    //state = 1;
    break;
  case 3:      // bubble chart page
    ClickedMenuButton();
    println("Going back to state home from BG");
    break;
  case 4:      // scatter graph page
    ClickedMenuButton();
    println("Going back to state home from SG");
    break;
  default:
    // menu
    ClickMenu();
  }
}
```

Edit:
to keep the description on the screen you have 3 changes to do: first, you declare a boolean global variable on top and set it to false by default :

```
//boolean to hold the info whether we draw description or not    
boolean show_ps_description=false;
```

Secondly, you change the Click on Playstation image event to inverse the previous boolean image instead of calling that draw method :

```
void mousePressed() {
  if(state == 2)
  {
    if ( mouseX > psImgX && mouseX < (psImgX + PS_Button.width) && mouseY > psImgY && mouseY < (psImgY + PS_Button.height)) 
    {
      //inverte the boolean
      show_ps_description=!show_ps_description;
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Lastly you call your drawing method (`drawPieChartDscpt()`) in your draw loop after checking if our boolean is true:

```
void draw() {
  switch(state) {
  case 2:
    // pie chart
    pieChartPage();
    drawMenuButton();
    
    if(show_ps_description)
      psImageDscpt.drawPieChartDscpt();
    
    break;
...
}
```

Comment: let me know if you can't figure out how to change that `drawPieChartDscpt()` to fix your second problem

Comment: Okay I did what you added and it works, but how do i make it so when the user presses the button the description stays on the screen of that page. So like until they click the same button again the description stays on the screen (hope that makes sense), thank you for your help

Comment: @migueldivo I edited the answer to fix that case, check what I added

Comment: Just tried it out and it works perfectly. Thank you for your help and for giving good explanations to your additions. Thank you very much